# Random lag spikes of 300-500ms - Any suggestions?

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

For the last few weeks I've been getting these infuriating lag spikes of between 300-500ms pretty much every 2-5mins which is so annoying and makes me miss key plays and has cost my death countless times. It's actually managed to get worse the last few days, where I see the reconnecting bar and I end up wondering into their turret and die. I've tried turning all my graphics on the lowest setting to fix it, I'm aware it's an internet issue not machine but you never know.

Hardware info:

Playing on a Macbook pro with nothing else open (Thought it was skype or dropbox so closed those)
Speed test readings so - 18.55 mbps download and a 1.84 mbps upload with an 11ms ping
Are there any terminal / router commands you'd recommend running to fix the issue? or anything that you've known to fix the issue before?

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: Does this happen only with LoL?  Or does it happen for whatever you're doing?  For the former, we might be able to help.  For the latter, SuperUser might be a better place; they're more about router and network config.

Comment: Not sure how to fix it, but just to help with terminology for searches and any future questions you might ask about this: that sounds like you might be  experiencing a high degree of ["jitter"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/203643/108003).

Comment: I've only noticed it happen on League but that's the only game I play. Ah thanks for the terminology I've not heard that before.

Comment: This isn't a very thoughtful question in that countless other people have asked this exact same question. But in terms of any advice, if you don't have a stable internet connection below about 170 ms, don't play league until it gets better or you get a new router.

Comment: Try [pingtest.net](http://www.pingtest.net/) and set the server to one near where your League region server is. It will give stats on ping, jitter, and packet loss, from which you might be able to discern some information on what's happening.

Comment: Pingtest, results are as follows: Unable to test packet loss, 22ms Ping, 17ms Jitter Your grade B*, Server Milton Keynes...I live in Southend, Essex..

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried restting your router (helped me out once).

Try reposising your router to a better angel.

Use aluminium foil (also helped me out).

See if their is any downloads going on( that kills any online gaming expirence).

Have you turned off all other devices connected to the internet e.g phones, laptops , tv's.

If all eles fails phone up your internet service provider to try and see if its their fault.

If it isn't their fault buy a new router. 
I hoped i helped you out.

Comment: Thanks for all the above comments, it's certainly insightful. As for the pingtest, results are as follows: Unable to test packet loss, 22ms Ping, 17ms Jitter Your grade B*, Server Milton Keynes...I live in Southend, Essex..

Comment: If the jitter is that high it is probably  your isp's fault or it could be bt's fault( as they own the cabinet or the green box).                                                 Do you have fiber optic?                                                                                      What is your isp?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the local internet provider is the main reason. Contact them to fix that for us - as long as you can indentify a pattern of the lagging occurences.

Second way is to use 3G mobile internet hotspot ^^

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons that **could** cause this problem:

- Broken/not fully working/ computer part - **cooling fan**, power cable (full processor/RAM).
- Software/virus/download going on in the background - to check running applications and their system values, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> --> Task Manager (Windows)
- Bad router - are you playing music? **/** are you/anybody else doing something online? - Sometimes the router can't operate with more devices at once.
- Game - any mods could cause this.